# How do you determine $T^{-1}(0,b)$ when $T(x) = 2x - [2x]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Defining $T(x) = 2x - [2x]$, where $[2x]$ is the integer part of $2x$.

I wish to find $T^{-n}(x) = (0,b)$ where $b < 1$.

I know the answer, it's a union of a  bunch of intervals that depend on $b$. My issue is, how do you find it?

The answer seems kind of complicated to me, and my instructor merely showed us this answer and told us that we can confirm it by "drawing it". Yeah, sure, that confirms it, but I don't want to confirm it, I want to know how to find it in case I had to solve it myself.

Comment: $T$ is not an injective function. Do you want the preimage of the interval $(0, b)$?

Comment: Your statements regarding the inverse of  T are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The range of T is K = [0,1).
Thus for a in K, letting x be in the inverse image of a,
2x - [2x] = a.  Since [2x] is an integer,
x = a/2 + n/2 for some integer n.
Whereupon the inverse image of a is the set a/2 + (1/2)Z.
In other words, { a/2 + n/2 : n in Z }.